# Changes to aeronautical charts

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts

Are there notes on changes to aeronautical charts available anywhere?

For example, when a new sectional comes out, many changes are charted. Is there any place I could find the specific changes that were made or, even better, documentation on why they were made?

Comment: Well there is definitely a source that lists all *airspace* changes.  More later.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to a chart are almost always changes to the underlying data. The FAA publishes changes via Transmittal Letters or through the National Flight Data Digest.

TLs typically cover changes to procedures…
https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Transmittal_Letters/

NFFDs typically deal with NAVAIDs, airways, fixes, airport diagrams, etc…
https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/Aero_Data/NFDD/

You would probably have to look through several of these for a given ARINC cycle to get a full picture of what is changing.

I do not believe the FAA puts out notices to individual charts (someone please correct me if I am mistaken).

Answer (score -1):

The FAA publishes a Chart Update Manual, or CHUM.  Between major chart revisions, we used to "CHUM our charts," mostly for things like cell phone towers.

Let the FAA be your guide!

General Information:
https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/

Chart User's Guide:
https://aeronav.faa.gov/user_guide/20230810/cug-complete.pdf

Comment: You've mentioned a Chart Update Manual, but you've linked to the Chart Users' Guide. I don't see anything about a CHUM on this page.

Comment: The FAA did not produce the CHUM. The CHUM (and then eCHUM) was obstacle data to be used with charts that were not frequently updated. Nevertheless, that does not exist anymore anyway.